# Installing an SSL certificate when using Retrofit

Tags: android, http, ssl, https, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit library in my android app to send post request to server and receive responses. my server is HTTP and i want to install ssl certificate on my server. after url changes from HTTP TO HTTPS, what i have to do in client side (android app)? changing base url to https://... is enough or other changes is needed?

Comment: Did you try to try before asking ?

Comment: server is not mine and i haven't access to it

Comment: i want to be sure before trying it

Comment: man I am talking about the Retrofit client

Comment: use postman to make sure 
https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: i'm using retrofit with http server and everything is ok, my question is if i install ssl on server, just changing retrofit base url is enough or other configurations is needed?

Comment: Its fine for use https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you need to change base url "HTTP" ot "HTTPS"

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to change HTTP to HTTPS locally in your Retrofit client